# C: what is wrong with this char pointer assignment?

Tags: c, string, pointers, variable-assignment, character

A newbie question:

I was practice assignment to a char pointer, but found there was nothing printed out. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char * option_string = NULL;
    option_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(5));
    memset(option_string, 0, sizeof(char) * 5);

    int j;
    for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        *option_string++ = 'a';
    }

    printf("print options_string: %s\n", option_string); //!nothing was printed out!
    free(option_string);
    return 0; 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that within the loop, you write `*option_string++`.  This means that once the loop is done, you're going to be pointing past the end of the string:

```
option_string at start
   |
   V
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
                             ^
                             |
                     option_string at end
```

Note that this reveals a second problem with your code: strings in C are null-terminated, but this string will eventually contain "aaaaa" and then… who knows?  Garbage, most likely, but you can't tell.  You need a six-length string.  Fixing the first problem means using simple indexing instead: `option_string[j] = 'a'`.  If you really want the `*option_string++` method, you'll have to save and restore `option_string` (`char * real_option_string = option_string; ... option_string = real_option_string;`), but I wouldn't recommend it.  Fixing both of these bugs, and a couple of style things, gives you:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char * option_string = calloc(6, sizeof(char));

    int j;
    for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        option_string[j] = 'a';
    }

    printf("print options_string: %s\n", option_string);
    free(option_string);
    return 0; 
}
```

The other thing I changed was your `malloc` usage.  I feel like `calloc` is a better stylistic choice here; `calloc(count, size)` allocates `count` objects of size `size`, and zeros them.  It's like `malloc(count*size)` plus a memset, but feels cleaner to me.  You also shouldn't have a cast on `malloc`/`calloc`/etc., generally speaking (it can obscure useful warnings), and you need to allocate *six* slots, like I said (so you can have the null-terminator, which is the zero-valued character, so we don't need to set it explicitly).  Combine that with the `option_string[j]` indexing mode, include the missing `stdlib.h` for `calloc` (you should have had it for `malloc`, too), and we're good to go!

Comment: Great, thanks! Here I added a temp var to store the initialized position of option_string. recover it before printing.

Comment: @tao: You're welcome!  Is there any particular reason you're using that method?  I think it's the worse of the two options, although it will definitely work.

Comment: Sorry for late reply! No special reason, I was just practicing the pointer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

You increment the pointer `option_string` which in turn makes it point past the end of string.

Try
    malloc(6);

```
for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    option_string[j] = 'a';
}
```

instead.

Comment: I forgot the pointer changed to point to some garbage. thanks!

Comment: Yes, I tried again to same the initialized position to a tem value.

Answer (score 8):

Your `malloc(sizeof(5))` seems wrong. What is the size of `5`? (Hint: It's not 5.)

Comment: @tao: No, the size of `5` is not 6 either. 5 is an integer, so `sizeof(5) == sizeof(int)`. *However*, your buffer needs to be six bytes long in order to hold a null-terminated string of length 5, which doesn't have anything to do with the size of integers.